# Changing entities' field to different type of field

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2, polymorphic-associations

Basically let's say I have a class - Car.
This class car has a field "user". Now there are different types of users - let's say "salesman", "cab driver", "examiner". All of these are classes on their own which in the long run would have different fields. 
Now let's say the car gets sold - then the owner has to change. Now comes the problem - in order to change the owner, the "owner" field on the user class must be something general - it can't be "salesman" because how would I then change the owner to "cab driver". 
I've heard of the terms polymorphic db and morphing around this topic but honestly I have no clue how to tackle this problem.

I looked up a guide and what it suggested worked to some point. What it did, was create an abstract class "owner" and create "examiner", "salesman", "cab driver" classes which extend the abstract class. The abstract class uses inheritance with single_table in which case a single table is created where all classes extending owner are stored and they can be told apart by the column "type". 
Saving entities through jpa worked fine with this solution, but when I want to find an owner by their id, it does not work, probably because my JpaRepository is trying to map a db row to the class Owner but since Owner is an abstract class, it can't create an instance of it.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = 
DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Owner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}


@Entity
@Data
@DiscriminatorValue("salesman")
public class Salesman extends Owner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long balance;
}


@Repository
public interface OwnerRepository extends JpaRepository<Owner, Long> {
}


@Service
public class OwnerService {

    @Autowired
    private OwnerRepository repo;

    public Owner getById(Long id) {
        return repo.getOne(id);
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to change the users of the car and do simple CRUD operations with them.

Currently I receive the following error when trying to use the JpaRepository method getOne():
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: ee.priit.polymorphism.model.Owner$HibernateProxy$GnSnpo6f["hibernateLazyInitializer"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: ee.priit.polymorphism.model.Owner$HibernateProxy$GnSnpo6f["hibernateLazyInitializer"])

Answer (score 0):

You can create jpa repository with paramterization

```
public interface OwnerRepository extends JpaRepository<Owner, Long>
```

`find()` will return `Salseman` type erased to `Owner` type. If you will create one more class that extends `Owner` let says `Examiner` when you will call `findAll` jpa will return you list of `Owner` and `Examiner` mixed together and erased to parent `Owner` type. At least it is latest jpa+hibernate version.

During data extraction jpa (hibernate) determines target entity type based on Discriminator column value and create target entity type accordingly.

If you want to fetch all `Owner` but only `Owner` that is `Salesman` paramterization like

```
public interface OwnerRepository extends JpaRepository<Salesman, Long>
```

will do the trick.

If you try to enable

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
```

...hibernate sql output, you will find exact select query structure. (Since you ask for jpa I assume you use spring or spring boot).

Comment: I aplogize - the OwnerRepository class was supposed to have the parameters<Owner, Long> to begin with. I was trying something out and forgot to change it back.

The solution I used since the beginning and which you suggested produces the error I added to the original post.

Comment: Could you please share stack-trace in your post then?